# Converting n to 0.n without converting to a string and back

Tags: math, decimal

Is there a mathematically sound and simple way of converting an integer value (n) to a new decimal or float value which is equal to 0.n? An example would be taking 123 as an input and producing 0.123.

The way I'm currently thinking of involves:

1. Convert the integer to a string.
2. Append "0." to the front of the string.
3. Convert the string to a decimal/float.

But is there a way of doing this without having to convert to a string and back with **no possibility of rounding errors**?

Comment: What language are you working with?

Comment: Go, which doesn't have accurate fixed point arithmetic, which when dealing with monetary values isn't good because of floating point rounding errors. I've instead redesigned my currency package to use shopspring's decimal package: https://github.com/shopspring/decimal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You find out the "length" of the number with a logaritmic function:

```
int length = (int)(Math.log10(n)+1);
```

Then you can simply divide you number with 10 on the length power:

```
double number = n / pow(10, length);
```

Comment: What is Math? What is pow? OP didn't specify where he wants to run the code.

Comment: This is an example code written in JAVA. It's easy enough to convert it into any language i'd assume...

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_math.asp

    var length = Math.log10(n)+1;
    var number = n / Math.pow(10, length);

Comment: Math modules are quite common so I'd expect this approach to work practically anywhere. I know for a fact that Javascript and Python and C++ and Lua and C# and PHP have logarithms and exponentiation.

Answer (score 2):

The following does it but as usual, you need to rely on the float representation of your language. Avoiding rounding errors will be language dependent.

```
while (n>=1) {
    n /= 10.;
}
return n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
decimal d = 0;

if(n < 10) d = 10
else if(n < 100) d = 100
else if(n < 1000) d = 1000
else if(n < 10000) d = 10000
else if(n < 100000) d = 100000
....

var result = n / d;
```

Comment: This is overly verbose and therefore error-prone ... logarithms and exponentiation (as shown in the selected answer) are a much better choice.